# jsPDF get the generated document as base64

Tags: jspdf

I´m trying to generate a PDF on my application, using something like this, from documentation:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();   

doc.html(document.body, {
   callback: function (doc) {
     doc.save();
   }
});
```

But what I need is to get this generated file, as a `base64` content, to send as an attachment on an email. Is there a way to get this directly on callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like below.

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

 pdf.html(document.getElementById('doc'), {
    callback: function (pdf) {

    // example text
    pdf.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
    pdf.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');

    var base = pdf.output('datauri'); // directly to base664

    console.log("base64 is  ");
    console.log(base);

    // you can generate in another format also  like blob
     var out = pdf.output('blob');
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(out); 
    reader.onloadend = function() { // for blob to base64
         base64data = reader.result; 
         console.log("base64 data is ");               
         console.log(base64data );
    }
    pdf.save('DOC.pdf');

    }
    })
```

You can see more on **output()** method in the following link.

[jspdf output() source code](http://www.rotisedapsales.com/snr/cloud2/website/jsPDF-master/docs/jspdf.js.html#line992)

Answer (score 7):

It's worth noting that the *datauri* option changes the document location, see the following snippet from jsPDF lib:

```
case 'datauri':
case 'dataurl':
    return global.document.location.href = datauri;
```

This is fine unless you are trying to use an **IFrame**, as it would cause its body to be replaced by an *embed* tag displaying the pdf just generated.

Instead, the safest option is to use *datauristring* as this simply returns the pdf in a base64 string:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

var base = pdf.output('datauristring'); // base64 string

console.log("base64 is ", base);
```

Honestly, I don't know why anybody would want to use the *datauri* option instead of *datauristring* as latter's behaviour it's what most people expect anyway.